# MySQL - What's the total cost in price for each person's total number of courses?

Tags: mysql

I am having problems working out a sum in a query. It requires a CAST I'm sure.

The query - I want to find out how much each parents total number of activities costs. The price of each activity is $5.50, therefore someone with 4 activities would be $22 total.

It requires 3 columns which are for Parent Name, total activities, and total cost.

I can't work out the total cost for each parent's total activities...

Please help

**code**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", P.parent_title, P.parent_fname, P.parent_sname) AS Parent,
COUNT(A.activity_name) AS Total_Activities
FROM Activity A, Child C, Parent P, ChildActivity
WHERE P.parent_id = C.parent_id
AND C.child_id = ChildActivity.child_id
AND A.activity_id = ChildActivity.activity_id
GROUP BY Parent
ORDER BY P.parent_sname, P.parent_fname
```

**Results example:** (actually lists 11 people)

```
  *Parent*        *Total Activities*
  MR James Dean         4
```

Comment: I'm sure enough it's homework that I added the homework tag

Comment: @user1335184 So, the results you're getting are the right ones but you just want to add another column with the amount for all the activities?

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho - Yes the results for the first two columns (parent and total activities) are correct, however I still require a 3rd column in the results, showing the total cost. Therefore James Dean, with 4 activies - $5.50 x 4 = $22.50 and so on. There are 11 parents in total, all with different number of activities, that I require the total cost of... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As this is homework, I can not give you the answer right away. Think it this way: You can apply math to column values :)

Comment: No problems. It's not homework however. I have tried sum's and * values, but I just want to display it in $...

Comment: So, now you get the final number but you are missing the `$` symbol?

Comment: No, I haven't got it yet. I'm looking at this as a solution?! CONCAT('$',CAST(=5.50,int)*A.activity_name)