# MySQL Query - How to multiply number values in rows in a singular column for multiple customers and show as price?

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to query a total price?

I want to multiply several number values and display the result in $ for several customers in my database?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - What's the the total cost in price for each person's total number of courses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167194/mysql-whats-the-the-total-cost-in-price-for-each-persons-total-number-of-cou)

Comment: You shouldn't ask question twice and you should properly tag them. If it is [tag:homework], then tag them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT u.user_id, sum(o.total_price) 
   FROM users u INNER JOIN order o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
   GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: I don't think think so. I need to display the results in $, therefore I would assume I would have to add that in the query. Also a * for multiplication. I need to multiply the value (e.g 4) in the column by a price (e.g $4) to get a column with a total price... (*e.g 4 x $4 would be $16). I want to repeat this sum and get totals for several customers....